# Why is FILE all-caps as in FILE*?

Tags: c, history

This just seems odd to me, most other things are lower case.

Is there some historical reason?

Comment: Its FILE* (all-caps).

Comment: I don't agree that this question is "not constructive". There probably is an unambiguous answer and historically interesting answer (which I'll verify when I find the time). Most likely `FILE` was originally a macro, and by convention macros have all-caps names. This would have been before `typedef` was introduced to the C language. The current C standard does not permit `FILE` to be defined as a macro; it implies, but does not explicitly state, that it should be a `typedef`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a macro.  Macros have historically had all caps in C.  Unfortunately recent trends appear to have broken that fact.

Small history lesson: Also, FILE was an io buffer abstraction in UNIX v7 libc stdio.  A FILE doesn't necessarily represent a physical file, just something that can do block IO.  Source:

http://www.bsdlover.cn/study/UnixTree/V7/usr/include/stdio.h.html

"file" was already defined by the kernel as well:

http://www.bsdlover.cn/study/UnixTree/V7/usr/include/sys/file.h.html

As someone else said here it's probably a typedef now, but I don't think C had typedefs back in '79 as it only just had structs.  Then again I wasn't born then so... :)

Comment: It is *not* a macro in all implementations, just a type alias of one form or another. (Cf., e.g., `/usr/include/stdio.h` on Darwin, where FILE is directly defined as part of a single `typedef struct { } FILE` declaration.) The fact remains that all other such struct type aliases in the standard library (`size_t`, `time_t`, even `fpos_t` in `stdio`) are written in an entirely different convention. The obvious name (which also avoids conflict with the kernel's `file`) is `file_t` (or `stream_t`, etc.). I've never seen a complete historical answer to this question.

Comment: Could you please correct the links? They are not working now.

Comment: `FILE` is not a macro in *any* conforming implementation. Section 7.21.1 of the C standard lists the macros defined in `<stdio.h>`; `FILE` isn't one of them. A strictly conforming program may declare a variable named `FILE` in an inner scope, even if it has `#include <stdio.h>`; making `FILE` a macro would break such programs. (It's likely that it was a macro before `typedef`s were added to the language.)

Answer (score 6):

It's all caps almost certainly because at least originally it was a macro. Nowadays, chances are pretty good that it's a typedef instead, but nobody changed the name to boot (and doing so would be a pretty lousy idea).

Comment: IOW, it is for historical and compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Rudy: Mostly, yes. Then again, even historically, the reasoning is pretty poor. The original reason for macros being all-caps was a subtle warning about function-like macros that might evaluate their arguments more than once. Using it for object-like macros was a foolish consistency from the beginning.

Comment: I disagree that using all-caps for object-like macros is a foolish consistency.  All-caps for *all* macros makes it easier to avoid name collisions.