# Standard library `FILE` type

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is FILE all-caps as in FILE*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949192/why-is-file-all-caps-as-in-file)

Why is the standard library `FILE` type written uppercase ?
Is it because of its opaque nature ?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a good question. The UNIX system types that are its rough contemporaries (e.g., `time_t`) have lower case names, like the built-in C types.

Comment: Their caps lock key was broken and the deadline was too short.

Comment: Originally though wouldn't simple file descriptors have been used instead?  (plain 'ol integers, and the built-in ones were lowercase: `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`.)  Maybe `FILE` was to differentiate between using a descriptor and using a file handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the naming convention used in C, upper case is typically used for preprocessor macros. My guess is that it originally was implemented as a macro expanding to the concrete type used by the library implementation.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1423297&page=10)

"Strictly speaking, in C the FILE type is a library defined (in stdio.h header) type alias (see typedef keyword). No need to use FILE type as such, only FILE* (pointer to FILE) type. It's (one of;) C language funny idioms.
As usually, FILE type alias denotes library defined structure, but don't use its members directly (it's implementation dependent entity)."

Also [this](http://ifa.hawaii.edu/~barnes/treecode/stdinc.h.html):

```
typedef FILE *stream;
```

Finally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949192/why-is-file-all-caps-as-in-file):

Answer (score 1):

It's not an opaque type, it's usually a C struct, but its fields are implementation defined.

I guess the uppercase is because history...

Comment: I would still call it "opaque" as long as the specification makes no promises about the properties of the underlying type or the contents of such objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but note that there are only a few types declared in the standard C library. Probably the `FILE` was the very first defined, and the *_t style wasn't yet invented.

Or maybe in primitive C versions it was a macro... think what happened before they invented the `typedef`:

```
#define FILE struct __file
```

Instead of:

```
typedef struct __file FILE;
```

Comment: You got your `#define` backwards...